# What is the name of this insect? Is it venomous or possess any threat to human life if someone gets stung?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

I found it in Northern part of India, on a mango tree. When I intended to move it away from home, it seems to bite like a snake with front part lifting like a king cobra.

This insect is 6-7 inches long, 1-2 inches wide, and appeared during summers.

[image: Top view of insect]

[image: Side view of insect]

Answer (score -1):

That looks like some kind of [lappet moth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasiocampidae) caterpillar. Although I am no expert in them, especially not species that would appear in India. But hopefully my answer gives you the right direction of research.

You can see some visually similar observations on iNaturalist:

- https://www.inaturalist.org/observations/42382365
- https://www.inaturalist.org/observations/40958993
- https://www.inaturalist.org/observations/40137289